# Create a multisite network for an existing installation

Tags: plugins, multisite, htaccess, installation

I have a website with some large number of posts like (75k posts).

Till now, i am using a plugin called Main Category As Sub-domain to convert categories into sub-domains.

**ISSUE - 1** → In recent wordpress 4.7 update, few functions of that plugins are depreciated. I don't think that plugin's author is going update it.

**ISSUE - 2** → I tried to use its alternative plugins, but they are having some permalink restrictions which are causing 404 errors for my existing posts. So, i cant use them.

My current permalink structure is `/%post_id%/%postname%/`

After all, I decided to convert my single WP into Multisite.

I followed all steps in [`codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network)

But after changing *.htaccess* and *wp-config.php*, I logged out.

**ISSUE - 3** →When i login again, i am not seeing anything new in *WP Dashboard*. (i.e) *Network* is not setup. I tried it many times but no use.

I am not able to understand what is causing this issue.

**ISSUE - 4** → Also, i tried to create an alternative WP multisite to export all category posts to specific sub-sites. I know this will work but taking long time to process exporting and importing as i can only export 2000-2500 posts at once.

---

**Files: .htaccess and wp-congig.php**

→ [.htaccess - https://pastebin.com/raw/Cg0EFqQn](https://pastebin.com/raw/Cg0EFqQn)

```
# BEGIN WordPress
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
# END WordPress

#CURL Timeout Increment
<IfModule mod_php5.c>
php_value CURLOPT_TIMEOUT_MS 30000
php_value CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT_MS 25000
</IfModule>

# BEGIN cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
# Manual editing of this file may result in unexpected behavior.
# To make changes to this file, use the cPanel MultiPHP INI Editor (Home >> Software >> MultiPHP INI Editor)
# For more information, read our documentation (https://go.cpanel.net/EA4ModifyINI)
<IfModule php5_module>
   php_flag asp_tags Off
   php_flag display_errors Off
   php_value max_execution_time 90
   php_value max_input_time -1
   php_value max_input_vars 3000
   php_value memory_limit 128M
   php_value session.gc_maxlifetime 1440
   php_value session.save_path "/var/cpanel/php/sessions/ea-php56"
   php_value upload_max_filesize 32M
</IfModule>
# END cPanel-generated php ini directives, do not edit
```

→ [Wp-Config - https://pastebin.com/raw/j3RGbVsa](https://pastebin.com/raw/j3RGbVsa) (Don't Mind, i removed my database details in *wp-config.php*)

```
/* Multisite */
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );

define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'mydomain.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);


/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */

/** Absolute path to the WordPress directory. */
if ( !defined('ABSPATH') )
    define('ABSPATH', dirname(__FILE__) . '/');

/** Sets up WordPress vars and included files. */
require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');
```

---

### MY IDEAS

1. Using .htaccess rules to redirect 404 errors when using alternative
   plugins.
2. Importing and Exporting posts with help of MySQL.

I don't know whether these are possible or not. But

- Please help me, setup a network for my site.
- Or provide any alternative idea.
- Any kind of response would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.